# How to get database specific datatypes in java?

Tags: java, database, ddl

Consider this code segment

```
Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

          connection = DriverManager.getConnection
             ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1521/xe", "abc", "def");
 DatabaseMetaData metaData=connection.getMetaData();
        ResultSet rsc= metaData.getColumns(null, "MYSCHEMA", "MYTABLE", null);
        while (rsc.next()){

            System.out.println(rsc.getString("COLUMN_NAME").toUpperCase());
            System.out.println(rsc.getString("TYPE_NAME").toUpperCase());
            System.out.println(rsc.getInt("COLUMN_SIZE"));
            System.out.println(rsc.getInt("DECIMAL_DIGITS"));   
            System.out.println(rsc.getString("IS_NULLABLE").toUpperCase()) ;
            System.out.println(rsc.getInt("ORDINAL_POSITION"));
            System.out.println(rsc.getInt("DATA_TYPE"));
            System.out.println("********************************************");
        }
```

With this code segment I can get to know that if suppose MYTABLE has a column whose name is MYTABLEID of type NUMBER in Oracle then how can I get to know that what will be the corresponding datatype name of NUMBER equivalent in Mysql or PostGresql ? Basically aim is to get database specific datatype. Like in Oracle we have CLOB datatype but in postgresql we have bytea as an equivalent datatype. I wanted database specific type so that I can create DDL (Create table statement) to create table in a particular database(from oracle to mysql or postgresql etc).

Comment: i think you will have to manually map these data types in your code

Comment: @MozenRath manually? Oh god. Then I am giving invitation to bugs thats for sure.. :(

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why not use `rsc.getObject` and make `instanceof` checks on the resulting object?

Comment: @Jonathan I want to prepare create table query as mentioned in question.. rsc.getObject() wont be useful right..Ex suppose you have to copy customer table from oracle to mysql,so how can you do that..datatypes of mysql is different from oracle..right..

Comment: Have you considered using an orm (hibernate/eclipselink) framework - if not for the dataaccess than at least for schema-creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create an XML file with info on each database and any specific database datatype (e.g. CLOB, or bytea), then I would use this info and retrieve it for any specific use you may have in your code.  Hope it helps.

Comment: If someone can share correct mapping information then it would be really good for all the three oracle,mysql,postgresql

Comment: it is available on the Internet only there is need to compile it - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype.html, http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-datatypes.html